# "DG categories" over other DG categories

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, dg-categories

The standard definition of a DG-category is "a category enriched in chain complexes over a commutative ring $k$".

Suppose I have a category enriched over some symmetric monoidal DG-category, for instance over the category of chain complexes of locally free sheaves over some space. How would I call this beast? Note that this usually will not be a DG-category anymore. The homs are complexes of locally free sheaves, they are not complexes of modules.

I can iterate: suppose I have a category enriched over a category enriched over a category of chain complexes over $k$. How would I call all these categories?

Is there a notion that unifies all of these? Some kind of $\infty$-DG category? Did anyone study these?

Comment: What's wrong with "enriched category over [whatever you have]"?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I think these categories are very similar to DG categories, for instance you can speak of cones, but since they are not strictly speaking DG categories I cannot apply results about DG to them

Comment: You can still apply results about enriched categories to them (and AFAIK many results on DG-categories are in fact results about enriched cats in disguise). Maybe it's not relevant to your problem, but -provided you don't care about size, and few people care, usually- this is the procedure with which you define strict $n$-categories: they are categories enriched on strict $(n-1)$-categories.

Comment: I believe that most inline with current mathematics will be to try to use the notion of a stable infinity-category tensored over [insert your infinity-category, quasi-coherent sheaves over some space in your example]. Then you will have inner Hom's which are given by universal property and lie in the category you are tensored over.